# Hibernate MySQL вывод списка

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

У меня главный класс, который всем рулит:

```
public class Runner {

    private static SessionFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        getList().stream().map(p -> p.toString())
        .forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

Метод:

```
public static List getList () {

        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        List<Pill> pills = session.createSQLQuery("select * from pills").list();
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();

        return pills;

    }
```

Он достает из базы списочек и выводит содержимое в консоль (по идее). **НО**

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@f446158 // Вот это!!
```

Как бы сделать так, чтобы выводились полезные данные? Метод toString() в классе Pill переопределен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело вот в чем оказалось: надо использовать было HQL а не SQL , ведь моя дб про java и какие-то объекты ничего не знала. Такие дела

Answer (score 0):

Очень осторожно предположу, что в стриме нужно либо использовать `deepToString()`, либо расписать проход по всем геттерам объекта...